# Fetch unique values from cross reference table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Right Now I have a cross reference table that looks like this:

```
       Table job2pos
╔═══════════╦═════════════╗
║  job_id   ║ position_id ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╣
║  1        ║  10         ║
║  2        ║  10         ║
║  2        ║  12         ║
║  3        ║  11         ║
║  3        ║  13         ║
║  4        ║  10         ║
║  5        ║  13         ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╝
```

I want to select all the `job_id` that have the `postion_id = 10` and `position_id = 12`, which would result in `job_id = 1,2,2,4`. But I only want `job_id = 2` to appear only once in my fetched result.

The code I tried are as follow:

```
$positions = ["10","12"];

$sql = "SELECT job2pos.job_id FROM job2pos
WHERE job2pos.pos_id IN (?,?)";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

foreach ($positions as $key => &$val) {
  $stmt->bindParam($key, $val, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
}

$stmt->execute();

var_dump($stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE));
```

And the above attempt will produce the follow result:

```
array(3) {
  [1]=> array(0) {}
  [2]=> array(0) {}
  [4]=> array(0) {}
}
```

So I did get unique values and the extra 2 is not repeating, but how do I make it so that the `job_id` does not appear as an index but instead an value in side an array?

- P.S. If you can point out any unnecessary code in my code that will be great as well.

Comment: Use `select distinct` with standard `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`

Comment: Or `array_keys` on your current result.

Comment: And please change ╬ to ╣ after **position_id**. It's too close to perfect.

Comment: @Mihailo How do I type that?

Comment: @Sarah Nice! Now it's perfect. Here's a link for anybody that's a [box drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character) enthusiast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Special `SELECT DISTINCT` construct will bring distinct values only from your query. So you can rewrite your code as:

```
$postions = ["10","12"];
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT job2pos.job_id FROM job2pos WHERE job2pos.pos_id IN (?,?)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

// btw you don't have to bind elements one by one
// you can pass array as an argument to execute:
$stmt->execute($positions);

print_r($stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```